# How to get source code for modbus slave(RTU) for pic microcontroller. Kindly suggest

Tags: modbus

I am looking for basic Modbus RTu slave code for PIC using rs485. Please guide me to get source code or develop source code &
What are function i need to take care while developing it

Answer (score 2):

[liblightmodbus](https://github.com/Jacajack/liblightmodbus) is a very lightweight, highly configurable, platform-independent Modbus RTU library.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could find: [freemodbus](http://www.opensourcepic.com/modbus.php).

There is a port to PIC32xx but I did not test it.

There used to be a bunch of projects implementing Modbus for PIC microcontrollers but most of them are old, with dead links and nowhere to be found anymore.

With Arduino & friends and SBCs running so cheap nobody seems to be into this kind of thing with PIC anymore.